# Select rows based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to use

```
data = data.loc['bids:']
```

to get all rows corresponding to the index.

SAMPLE DATA FROM TEXT FILE:

```
 {"offset":"14726172634","bids":[["871094.22000","0.00200000","0.00200000","0","1081537351","29194","5","14726172633","1"],["871076.11000","0.00808000","0.00808000","0","1081537130","623964","5","14726172043","1"],["871073.96500","0.00100000","0.00100000","0","1081537185","29194","5","14726172231","1"]]],
"asks":[["875644.72000","0.00200000","0.00200000","0","1081606189","29194","5","14726356256","1"],["875669.77637","0.01000000","0.01000000","0","1081606227","29194","5","14726356379","1"],["875678.92000","0.00600000","0.00600000","0","1081606263","29194","5","14726356488","1"],["875731.74364","0.03000000","0.03000000","0","1081606233","29194","5","14726356393","1"],
```

CODE SAMPLE:

```
 data = pd.read_csv('20190523-012523_product_5_snapshot_14726172634_14728561053.txt', lineterminator= str(']'), low_memory= False, error_bad_lines=False, header= None)#, names= ['a','d','f','r','y','h','n','m','k'])

 new = data[1].str.split("[", n = 1, expand = True)
 data[1]= new[0]
 data[10]= new[1]
 data.drop(data.index[-1], inplace=True)
 data[10]= new[1].str.strip('[').str.strip('"')

 data = data.set_index([1,2])
 data = data.loc[:,[10]]
 data = data.loc['bids:']
```

DATA SAMPLE:

```
bids:  0.002000   871094.22000
       0.008080   871076.11000
       0.001000   871073.96500
bids:  0.005000   871042.87000
       0.005000   871038.55000
       0.001000   871032.90156
```

CODE OUTPUT:

```
bids:  0.002000   871094.22000
bids:  0.005000   871042.87000
```

How to get the 6 rows please? The purpose is to filter among other index labels.

The index output is :

```
Index(['bids:', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       ...
       'asks:', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       ...
       'bids:', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       ...'],
      dtype='object', name=1, length=505148)
```

Comment: @ALollz just added

Comment: I assume Pandas is considering there is no index when the row index is ' '

Comment: No, it is considering the index the empty string. You probably want to create a MultIndex, where the first level is ['bids', 'asks'] and the second level is that first small number.

Comment: It would help if you could include code that creates the DataFrame, or at least the sample version that you're showing. For example, something like `df = pd.DataFrame({'some_column': [1.0, 2.0....`. This way, we'll know what the structure of your DataFrame is like, and we can copy-paste the code to develop and test our answers. Right now, it's not presented in a standard format that tells us anything about what's really going on with your data. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike the raw data comes from an text file which I parse. Do you still think it should be posted? It could make the post difficult to read. thanks

Comment: I would post enough to get at the ground truth of the structure of the database, even if it's faked up to get at the structure of the portion you've posted. The following link helps everyone the more people understand it and take it in: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added some data hoping it make it easier to understand

Comment: `df.index=df.index.to_series().replace('',np.nan).ffill()` ?

Comment: @mamadede - What is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: `df.reset_index()['index'].values`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
print (data)
                           10
1    2                       
bids 0.00200000  871094.22000
     0.00808000  871076.11000
     0.00100000  871073.96500
asks 0.00200000  875644.72000
     0.01000000  875669.77637
     0.00600000  875678.92000
     0.03000000  875731.74364
bids 0.00200000  871094.22000
     0.00808000  871076.11000
     0.00100000  871073.96500

print (data.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['asks', 'bids'], 
                   ['0.00100000', '0.00200000', '0.00600000', 
                    '0.00808000', '0.01000000', '0.03000000']],
           codes=[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 0, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 0]],
           names=[1, 2])
```

Solution for first values by first level of `MultiIndex`, with duplicated values:

```
s = data.index.get_level_values(0).to_series()
mask = s.ne(s.shift())
print (mask)
1
bids     True
bids    False
bids    False
asks     True
asks    False
asks    False
asks    False
bids     True
bids    False
bids    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool

df = data[mask.values]
print (df)
                           10
1    2                       
bids 0.00200000  871094.22000
asks 0.00200000  875644.72000
bids 0.00200000  871094.22000

df = df.xs('bids', drop_level=False)
print (df)
                           10
1    2                       
bids 0.00200000  871094.22000
     0.00200000  871094.22000
```

If there is no `MultiIndex`:

```
print (data)
              2             10
1                             
bids  0.00200000  871094.22000
bids  0.00808000  871076.11000
bids  0.00100000  871073.96500
asks  0.00200000  875644.72000
asks  0.01000000  875669.77637
asks  0.00600000  875678.92000
asks  0.03000000  875731.74364
bids  0.00200000  871094.22000
bids  0.00808000  871076.11000
bids  0.00100000  871073.96500
```

---

```
print (data.index)
Index(['bids', 'bids', 'bids', 'asks', 'asks', 'asks', 'asks', 'bids', 'bids',
       'bids'],
      dtype='object', name=1)

s = data.index.to_series()
mask = s.ne(s.shift())
print (mask)
1
bids     True
bids    False
bids    False
asks     True
asks    False
asks    False
asks    False
bids     True
bids    False
bids    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool

df = data[mask.values].loc['bids']
print (df)
              2             10
1                             
bids  0.00200000  871094.22000
bids  0.00200000  871094.22000
```